# Unexpected Token : (colon) in Typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am new to TypeScript. I m getting some error while runing a simple TypeScript program.

When using any form of "variable: type; " in my TypeScript code. 
I m getting Syntax error about an unexpected token ':' while running the file.

For eg : 
File - main.ts

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
let greeter = new Greeter("World");
```

I m able to compile the file but at time of running, getting following error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :     
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)     
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
```

The expected output should be :
Hello World

Can anyone please let me know what i m missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code does not produce that TypeScript compiler error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greeting%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20this.greeting%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22World%22)%3B You are likely trying to run the TypeScript directly in a JavaScript engine instead of compiling first and running the compiled script.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, I m first compiling and then running the typescript file.

Comment: Right, you're running the TypeScript file (.ts), not the output of the compilation. which is a JavaScript file (.js).

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, what I encounter is that:
 1. `greeting` should be initialised
 `greeting: string = '';`
 2. Greeter does not require a parameter.
 Add a constructor.

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string = '';
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }
}
```

You can remove the `initialisation` of the greeting if you added the constructor (given the example above.

I am using `typescript v3.4.2` and `tsc v1.20150623.0`

**Already answered by Vivek** See comments above.

Comment: After using this code, still i m getting the same problem.
    
greeting: string = '';
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)

Note : I m first compiling then running the file. I m also using the same typescript version.